# Need an example of a facebook fans page that has a tab app which is getting extended permission?

Tags: facebook

Let's say I have a 520px "page app" that sits in a tab in a facebook fans page.

Is it possible this "page app" gets extended permission from the user to know more info about the user within the 520 px?

That means user approve the permission request in the 520px region and after that they continue to use the app in the 520 px.

I couldn't find any branding fans page doing this... Can anyone give me a link?

Comment: There you go
http://www.facebook.com/victoriassecret?sk=app_214280565251684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing special about the Facebook Apps inside [page tabs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) but:

1. The `signed_request` contains an extra parameter (`page`)
2. Its frame is of 520px or 810px width

Now brands main purpose of the Facebook pages is attracting fans to maximize their reach. This is why "allowing" an application is not needed but "encouraging" liking the page is the target.

Check my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/) about this for more info (check real world examples). Also the [RedBull Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/redbull) is a great example (with nice illustration to encourage liking the page).

From there, how to ask for extended permission is really a no-brainer because at the end a "page tab app" is a Facebook App and everything in the documentation applies to it!